# HwndSource does not display the Adorner layer

Tags: wpf, interop, adorner, adornerlayer, adornerdecorator

When I host WPF controls that use adorners (the error border of the textbox) in a HwndSource the adorners are not shown. It seems that the adorner layer is not there. Why is that so and what can I do against it? Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AdornerLayer is usually part of the default template of the Window class.

If you are customizing the Window template or host controls in something else than a Window; you'll have to create the AdornerLayer yourself.

This can be done by wrapping your WPF controls inside a System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator:

```
hwndSource.RootVisual = new AdornerDecorator { Child = yourTextBox };
```